# What is MACID?

Tags: haskell, happstack

I've recently found the [HAppS](http://happs.org/) and [Happstack](http://happstack.com/) projects, and the latter notes that one of its missions is to "leverage use of MACID".

What exactly is MACID ?

Comment: Not answering your question, but you might not be aware that happstack is the successor to happs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found some [info about MACID](http://74.125.77.132/search?q=cache:xmd6jfLW-_MJ:tutorial.happstack.com/tutorial/introductiontomacid+happ+macid&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk), which says:

> MACID is the Happstack storage
>   mechanism that allows you to use
>   whatever data structure you want to
>   hold your permanent data, without
>   worrying about getting it into and out
>   of tabular form fit for storage in a
>   traditional rdbms.

I also found someone saying that MACID data will be consistent and permanent (following the [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) principle) and so on, so that you could pull the power on your computer, start the system back up, and everything would be left in memory as-is.

Also found a description of the [MACID acronym](http://www.bluishcoder.co.nz/2006/04/haskell-application-server-happs.html):  *Monadic ACID transaction service*.

Answer (score 2):

It's the old name for what's now called acid-state, I think.